# Comparison of serialized objects on Spark rawcomparator

Tags: hadoop, serialization, apache-spark

I’m trying to find out how serialized objects of the types `String (java.lang.String)` and `Text (org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)` get compared on Spark. Either of the types should be used as key of elements of an RDD. So I would like to know if there are differences in the way objects of these types get compared. This might be relevant in the following cases:

1. `RDD.saveAsObjectFile` and `SparkContext.objectFile` that support saving an RDD as serialized objects and loading it.
2. `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` as storage level that is provided when calling `RDD.persist()`.

Hadoop provides the `RawComparator` as Extension of Java’s `Comparator`. It allows to compare objects read from stream, without deserializing them into objects. `WritableComparator` implements the `RawComparator` interface for `WritableComparable` types, such as `Text`, while there seems to be no implementation for `String`. [1, p. 96]

```
package org.apache.hadoop.io;
import java.util.Comparator;

public interface RawComparator<T> extends Comparator<T> {

public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2);

}
```

So the question is: How deals Spark with that, p. ex. for an RDD in the cases of 1. and 2., when `reduceByKey()` is called, as stated in the listing below?
Have objects of both types to be deserialized, before they can be compared? Or is there any mechanism like the `RawComparator` interface on Hadoop?
I have already searched in the documentation, on the web and even in the Spark sources, but wasn’t able to find the answer yet.

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,CustomType>> loadedParsedContents = sc.objectFile(pathToObjectFile);
JavaPairRDD<String, CustomType> parsedContents 
    = loadedParsedContents.mapToPair(...);
JavaPairRDD<String, CustomType> reducedContents = parsedContents.reduceByKey(...);
reducedContents.count();
```

[1] White T (2012) Hadoop; The definitive guide. O'Reilly, Sebastopol, CA.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very interesting question, and the answer is in the process of changing. In general operations in Spark is done on deserialized objects - but this is changing in Spark SQL as some operations can now be done directly on serialized objects.

Comment: Hello Holden, thank you for your reply! This is very helpful.